# Prove that for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, a sequence of $n^3$ elements either has $n$ equal elements or a monotone subsequence with $n$ elements.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Prove that $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, a sequence with $n^3$ elements either has $n$ equal elements or a monotone subsequence with $n$ elements (strictly increasing or strictly decreasing).

I tried to apply the pigeonhole principle but had no idea how to go on. Anyone can give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without $n$ equal element, each element occurs at most $n-1$ occurrences
and so there are at least $n^3/(n-1)>n^2+n+1$ distinct elements.
Deleting repetitions gives a sequence of at least $n^2+n+1$
distinct elements. Now apply [Erdos-Szekeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem).